# Interpolate seconds to milliseconds in dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, interpolation

I have a sorted dataset by timestamps in seconds. However I need to somehow convert it to millisecond accuracy.

Example

```
    dataset = [
        # UNIX timestamps with reading data
        (0,  0.48499),
        (2,  0.48475),
        (3,  0.48475),
        (3,  0.48473),
        (3,  0.48433),
        (3,  0.48403),
        (3,  0.48403),
        (3,  0.48403),
        (3,  0.48403),
        (3,  0.48403),
        (5,  0.48396),
        (12, 0.48353),
    ]
```

Expected output (roughly)

```
    interpolated = [
        # Timestamps with millisecond accuracy
        (0.0,  0.48499),
        (2.0,  0.48475),
        (3.0,  0.48475),
        (3.14,  0.48473),
        (3.28,  0.48433),
        (3.42,  0.48403),
        (3.57,  0.48403),
        (3.71,  0.48403),
        (3.85,  0.48403),
        (3.99,  0.48403),
        (5.0,  0.48396),
        (12.0, 0.48353),
    ]
```

I don't have much experience with `Pandas` and I've gone through `interpolate` and `drop_duplicates` but couldn't figure out how to go about this.

I would think this is a common problem so any help appreciated. Ideally I want to **spread evenly** the numbers.

Comment: What is your rule of conversion? I saw that only those rows whose first column = 3 were converted but why adding 0.14 to each row?

Comment: @CodeDifferent just did some rough math on paper.. trying to split evenly those numbers on the 3rd second. The rule doesn't matter so much I think, it's just approximation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `apply` methods. I didn't come up with a specific method like `interpolate` in this case, but there might be a more pythonic way.

### Code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe
dataset = [(0, 0.48499), (2, 0.48475), (3, 0.48475), (3, 0.48473), (3, 0.48433), (3, 0.48403), (3, 0.48403), (3, 0.48403), (3, 0.48403), (3, 0.48403), (5, 0.48396), (12, 0.48353)]
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['t', 'value'])

# Convert UNIX timestamps into the desired format
df.t = df.groupby('t', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.t + np.linspace(0, 1, len(df)))
```

### Output:

| t | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.48499 |
| 2 | 0.48475 |
| 3 | 0.48475 |
| 3.14286 | 0.48473 |
| 3.28571 | 0.48433 |
| 3.42857 | 0.48403 |
| 3.57143 | 0.48403 |
| 3.71429 | 0.48403 |
| 3.85714 | 0.48403 |
| 4 | 0.48403 |
| 5 | 0.48396 |
| 12 | 0.48353 |

### (Input:)

| t | value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.48499 |
| 2 | 0.48475 |
| 3 | 0.48475 |
| 3 | 0.48473 |
| 3 | 0.48433 |
| 3 | 0.48403 |
| 3 | 0.48403 |
| 3 | 0.48403 |
| 3 | 0.48403 |
| 3 | 0.48403 |
| 5 | 0.48396 |
| 12 | 0.48353 |