# Pandas simple groupby and apply complains "Columns must be same length as key"

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

Essentially I have a table of timestamps and some data and want to group by the same timestamps and change the timestamps on a grouping basis. I got something working with [Interpolate seconds to milliseconds in dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101412/interpolate-seconds-to-milliseconds-in-dataset/71101759#71101759)

The solution seems to work fine for many rows but not for simple datasets and I can't figure out why. I've narrowed it down to a simple example below.

Data:

```
    t  val
    0  0.3
    0  0.2
    0  0.6
    0  0.4
```

Expected result:

```
    t  val
    1  0.3
    1  0.2
    1  0.6
    1  0.4
```

Code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0.3], [0, 0.2], [0, 0.6], [0, 0.4]], columns=["t", "val"])

# Group by timestamp and add +1 to each (just for demonstration)
df.t = df.groupby("t", group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.t + 1)
```

This raises `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you simply need to add a fixed value, why would you groupby? Just do `df['t'] += 1` no?

Comment: @mozway it's a simplified example to demonstrate the problem. The real life example is sth like `df.t + np.linspace(0, (len(df)-1)/len(df), len(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need output values to new column use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with specify column after `groupby` for processing:

```
df.t = df.groupby('t')['t'].transform(lambda x: x + 1)
```

---

Linked solution with `np.linspace` should be changed:

```
df.t = df.groupby('t')['t'].transform(lambda x: x + np.linspace(0, 1, len(x)))
print (df)
          t  val
0  0.000000  0.3
1  0.333333  0.2
2  0.666667  0.6
3  1.000000  0.4
```

Or add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df.t += df.groupby('t').cumcount()
```

Comment: Thanks, this guided me to the right direction!